# Kubernetes on Docker Desktop does not recognize local images

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-desktop

I am trying to deploy Windows Container image on the following software stack

```
Windows 10 Pro + Docker Desktop + Embedded Kubernetes in docker desktop
```

Due to some reason `'embedded kubernetes'` does not recognize `'local images'` no matter whatever `--image-pull-policy` was set

Docker images

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> docker images
REPOSITORY                             TAG        IMAGE ID       CREATED        SIZE
myimg                                  final      90c09acbfc59   15 hours ago   5.45GB
```

Kubectl run

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> kubectl run --image=myimg:final tskuberun
```

Pod output

```
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                From               Message
  ----     ------     ----               ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  25s                default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/tskuberun to docker-desktop
  Normal   BackOff    23s (x2 over 24s)  kubelet            Back-off pulling image "myimg:final"
  Warning  Failed     23s (x2 over 24s)  kubelet            Error: ImagePullBackOff
  Normal   Pulling    9s (x2 over 25s)   kubelet            Pulling image "myimg:final"
  Warning  Failed     8s (x2 over 25s)   kubelet            Failed to pull image "myimg:final": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 192.168.65.5:53: no such host
  Warning  Failed     8s (x2 over 25s)   kubelet            Error: ErrImagePull
```

However, when I execute docker run it pulled the local image.  Following worked as expected

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> docker run myimg:final
```

I googled for the answer but most of the links were related to Unix flavors and Minikube.

Only few links were related to `Docker desktop + embedded kubernetes`, but unfortunately none resolved the issue

I am struggling to get rid of this issue.  Any help is highly appreciated

**EDIT**

On further investigation, I observed that `'Docker desktop'` refers to local images in case had I selected option `"Switch to Linux Containers"`

Kubectl run for Linux image

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> kubectl run --image=wphp --image-pull-policy=IfNotPresent lntest


PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> kubectl describe pod/lntest

Events:
  Type     Reason     Age               From               Message
  ----     ------     ----              ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  40s               default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/lntest to docker-desktop
  Normal   Pulled     2s (x4 over 39s)  kubelet            Container image "wphp" already present on machine
  Normal   Created    2s (x4 over 39s)  kubelet            Created container lntest
  Normal   Started    2s (x4 over 39s)  kubelet            Started container lntest
```

It appears that this issue occurs only for 'Windows containers' ie Docker desktop does NOT refer local images had I selected option `'Switch to Windows Containers'`

Answer (score 4):

Allthough `imagePullPolicy: never` should do the trick for you, there could be some certificate related issues.

Personally I avoided using locally built Docker images because of those issues.

You can try to integrate docker push to docker hub in your workflow or build a docker registry in your kubernetes cluster e.g. using https://www.linuxtechi.com/setup-private-docker-registry-kubernetes/

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I edited my post and also it appears that the link you provided is for linux whereas I am working on Windows

Comment: You are right, allthogh the Kubernetes ressource should work regardless of your OS. You just have to find a way to generate self signed cert using Windows

Comment: `imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent` is also fine when testing locally developed images with Docker Desktop + embedded Kubernetes

Comment: Also if you can't see your images in Rancher Desktop, it may be because you are using `docker` for your cli commands, and Rancher Desktop is configured for `containerd` and `nerdctl` for the Container Engine.  If you switch your docker calls to nerdctl calls, you may find your images are pulled now.

Answer (score 0):

The VM used by Docker Desktop is unable to access the internet. You'll have to sort out that networking.